# Change occurrences of sum(something) to something_sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Admittedly I'm terrible with RegEx and pattern replacements, so I'm wondering if anyone can help me out with this one as I've been trying now for a few hours and in the process of pulling my hair out.

Examples:

```
sum(Sales) needs to be converted to Sales_sum
max(Sales) needs to be converted to Sales_max
min(Revenue) needs to be converted to Revenue_min
```

The only available prefixed words will be `sum, min, max, avg, xcount` - not sure if this makes a difference in the solution.

Hopefully that's enough information to kind of show what I'm trying to do. Is this possible via RegEx?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... That's not complex... Replace `/(sum|min|max|avg|xcount)\((.*?)\)/g` with `"$2_$1"`...

Comment: All relative as I'm terrible with Regex :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few possible ways, for example :

```
var str = "min(Revenue)";
var arr = str.match(/([^(]+)\(([^)]+)/);
var result = arr[2]+'_'+arr[1];
```

`result` is then `"Revenue_min"`.

Here's a more complex example following your comment, handling many matches and lowercasing the verb :

```
var str = "SUM(Sales) + MIN(Revenue)";
var result = str.replace(/\b([^()]+)\(([^()]+)\)/g, function(_,a,b){
   return b+'_'+a.toLowerCase()
});
```

Result : `"Sales_sum + Revenue_min"`

Comment: Can this be evolved to include all occurances to loop over? Such as SUM(Sales) + SUM(Sales).

Comment: Absolute genius. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
var input   = 'sum(Sales)',
    matches = input.match(/^([^(]*)\(([^)]*)/),
    output  = matches[2] + '_' + matches[1];

console.log(output); // Sales_sum
```

Also:

```
var input  = 'sum(Sales)',
    output = input.replace(/^([^(]*)\(([^)]*)\)/, '$2_$1');
```

Comment: Can the first answer be evolved to include all occurances to loop over? Such as SUM(Sales) + SUM(Sales).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` with tokens:

```
'sum(Sales)'.replace(/(\w+)\((\w+)\)/, '$2_$1')
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution to my needs (although I'm still appreciative of everyone's answers) - is there any way of getting the second word after _ to be lowercase in this regex? I.e. SUM(Sales) would become Sales_sum and not Sales_SUM.

Answer (score 0):

Using a whitelist for your list of prefixed words:

```
output = input.replace(/\b(sum|min|max|avg|xcount)\((.*?)\)/gi,function(_,a,b) {
    return b.toLowerCase()+"_"+a;
});
```

Added `\b`, a word boundary. This prevents something like "haxcount(xorz)" from becoming "haxorz_xcount"

Comment: This is great, but the main problem is that SUM(Sales) wouldn't be caught, and if it was then SUM(Sales) would then become Sales_SUM, and it should be Sales_sum - sorry. I should have said that in my question.